# Need to start Openshift oc client with passwords with special characters

Tags: openshift

I am automating some stuff and I need to start the oc client but the password contains special characters.
So, I need to start a command prompt first and then pass the command so we get:

cmd /K "oc login --username="username" --password="password""

But it does not like that.

I have tried various combination but no joy.

Of course if I use the command directly, it works fine. The issue is because everything is enclosed in double-quotes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use escape character.
look into [this][1]:
https://support.remote.it/hc/en-us/articles/360046978852-Passing-passwords-which-contain-special-characters-on-the-command-line

[1]:

Comment: Please provide an example of using this with the OP's original question.